# Rails feature specs: external Google font API is called, but I don't know where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, phantomjs, capybara, google-font-api

When I run my Rails feature specs without internet connection, tests fail with the following reason:

```
  3) Creating user textarea fullscreen feature of "about" textarea shows the fullscreen toggler on hover
     Failure/Error: visit new_user_path

     Capybara::Poltergeist::StatusFailError:
       Request to 'http://127.0.0.1:65001/en/users/new' failed to reach server, check DNS and/or server status - Timed out with the following resources still waiting http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fredericka+the+Great
     # /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6@a4aa2/gems/poltergeist-1.13.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:376:in `command'
     # /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6@a4aa2/gems/poltergeist-1.13.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:35:in `visit'
     # /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6@a4aa2/gems/poltergeist-1.13.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/driver.rb:97:in `visit'
     # /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6@a4aa2/gems/capybara-2.12.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:252:in `visit'
     # /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6@a4aa2/gems/capybara-2.12.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
     # ./spec/features/users/new_spec.rb:137:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I suspect this being caused by a google font that I reference, but I have downloaded the font locally and load it like this in my SASS:

```
@font-face
  font-family: 'Fredericka the Great'
  font-style: normal
  font-weight: 400
  src: local('Fredericka the Great'), local('FrederickatheGreat'), asset-url('assets/fredericka_the_great.woff2') format('woff2')
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215
```

So I don't see any reference to `http://fonts.googleapis.com` in my code. Searching for this exact string over the whole project doesn't give any results, either.

How can I prevent this problem? I don't want PhantomJS to contact to any non-local resource anyways, as it slows down tests.

Comment: Have you added any gems for google fonts previously?

Comment: Hard to say... I remember some font gem that I installed once, but I don't know. I also have `font-awesome-rails`, but I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: Please check your application.css once. Make sure you are not requiring anything as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: my `application.css` wasn't correctly recompiled when testing, so it required an old version.

After doing a manual `$ rake assets:precompile` the google font api source wasn't called anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want Poltergeist/PhantomJS to access any resource outside 127.0.0.1 use the whitelist functionality provided by Poltergeist.  When registering your :poltergeist driver specify the `:url_whitelist` option

```
Capybara.register_driver(:poltergeist) do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, url_whitelist: ['http://127.0.0.1'])
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a good hint. Though it doesn't answer my question.